# Excel VBA connect to MySql server

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I set up a test database at db4free.net and uploaded a copy of the northwind training database to it, to see if I could pull some information to an excel workbook and keep getting the generic unspecified/automation error.

I included "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library" in the references and even tried 6.1 for good measure.

Before anyone freaks out at me including the username and password; the only thing that exists on this test database is a training dataset. I have ZERO personal information stored there.

Here is my code:

```
Sub sqlTest()
    'Declare some strings to hold the connection string and the SQL statement
    Dim cnStr As String
    Dim sqlStr As String
    
    'Define a connection and a recordset to hold extracted information
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rcSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rcSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'connection string to connect to db4free.net
    cnStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=85.10.205.173;DATABASE=resumedemo;PORT=3306;UID=jwaycaster;PWD=resumedemo123;"
    
    'Test SQL query
    sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM `Employees`"
    
    'This is where it crashes
    oConn.Open cnStr
    
    oConn.CommandTimeout = 900
    
    rcSet.Open sqlStr, oConn
    
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rcSet
    
    rcSet.Close
    
    oConn.Close
End Sub
```

I've search around several related topics and can't seem to find the answer. Hopefully I'm missing something simple.

EDIT for posterity: After reading responses I realized that the drivers are not installed on this computer (I'm visiting relatives and can't believe I forgot to check that). After installing the drivers and updating my references my code executes just fine, but I would suggest using CDP1802's instead.

Comment: You have not initialised the connection object. Either you need the `New` keyword when you define the oConn variable or you need to initialise it separately before calling the Open method.

Comment: What line of code errors?

Comment: Code works for me. Have you installed the MySQL ODBC driver (and with the correct 32/64 version?)

Comment: Installing the driver was the last part of the puzzle.  I'm out of town visiting relatives and trying to get something useful done on my mothers craptop.  I spent hours staring at my computer screen last night and never once even thought about the driver not being installed on this machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sometimes can be useful to handle the errors yourself. Add references to

1. Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
2. Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects RecordSet 6.0 Library

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub sqlTest()

    ' credentials
    Const SERVER = "85.10.205.173"
    Const DB = "resumedemo"
    Const UID = "jwaycaster"
    Const PWD = "resumedemo123"
      
    'Define a connection and a recordset to hold extracted information
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection, rcSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnStr As String, n As Long, msg As String, e
    
    'connection string to connect to db4free.net
    cnStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=" & SERVER & _
            ";PORT=3306;DATABASE=" & DB & _
            ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";"
    
    'Test SQL query
    Const SQL = "SELECT * FROM `Employees`"
    
    ' connect
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    'oConn.CommandTimeout = 900
    
    On Error Resume Next
    oConn.Open cnStr
    If oConn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For Each e In oConn.Errors
            msg = msg & vbLf & e.Description
        Next
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "ERROR - Connection Failed"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Connected to database " & oConn.DefaultDatabase, vbInformation, "Success"
    End If
    
    ' run query
    Set rcSet = oConn.Execute(SQL, n)
    If oConn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        msg = ""
        For Each e In oConn.Errors
            msg = msg & vbLf & e.Description
        Next
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "ERROR - Execute Failed"
    Else
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rcSet
        MsgBox SQL & " returned " & n & " records", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    oConn.Close
    
End Sub
```